# sorting dataframe python by alphabets then by year

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I am trying to sort the following data frame first in alphabetical order, and  within that alphabetical order I want the date (mmddyear) to be in chronological order. i.e. I have this data frame:

```
0 A11 01011997 
1 C11 07202005    
2 A12 02011997    
3 B12 12102001    
4 A13 10012000    
5 B11 11012001
6 A00 01101980
```

and I want to sort it to be of this form:

```
A11 01011997
A00 01101980    
A12 02011997    
A13 10012000    
B11 11012001    
B12 12102001    
C11 07202005
```

This is the dataframe I used in python.

```
sales = [('account', ['A11', 'C11', 'A12','B12','A13','B11']),
       ('date', [1011997, 7202005,2011997,12102001,10012000,11012001])
     ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(sales)
```

I tried `sales = sales.sort_values(by=['account'])`, and that sorts everything in alphabetical order. When I apply `sales = sales.sort_values(by=['date'])`, everything becomes out of order.

Any suggestions?

Comment: sales = sales.sort_values(by=['account', 'date'])?

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort on both fields using `df.sort_values(['account', 'date'])`.

But you can't just sort the data frame when the date is represented as a string or an integer because in many cases you will get the wrong order, e.g. integer 1011997 sorts before 1021980 although the latter represents a date in 1980. Similarly `'01011997'` sorts before `'01021980'`.

So convert the dates into `datetime`s first. Here I assume that the date column contains strings because your sample data suggests that.

```
import pandas as pd

sales = [('account', ['A11', 'A11', 'C11', 'A12','B12','A13','B11']),
         ('date', ['01011997', '01021980', '07202005', '02011997', '12102001', '10012000', '11012001'])]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(sales)

>>> df.sort_values(['account', 'date'])
  account      date
0     A11  01011997
1     A11  01021980
3     A12  02011997
5     A13  10012000
6     B11  11012001
4     B12  12102001
2     C11  07202005
```

In this case row 1 should sort before row 0, but it doesn't because the column is sorted lexicographically. To fix that convert `df['date']` to dtype `datetime64` then sort:

```
>>> df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m%d%Y')
>>> df
  account       date
0     A11 1997-01-01
1     A11 1980-01-02
2     C11 2005-07-20
3     A12 1997-02-01
4     B12 2001-12-10
5     A13 2000-10-01
6     B11 2001-11-01

>>> df.sort_values(['account', 'date'])
  account       date
1     A11 1980-01-02
0     A11 1997-01-01
3     A12 1997-02-01
5     A13 2000-10-01
6     B11 2001-11-01
4     B12 2001-12-10
2     C11 2005-07-20
```

which looks correct.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to keep the date in its original format i.e. (mmddyear)? the dtype datetime 64 won't let me keep the original format

Comment: Thanks, I think there is a bug though. If you change A11 in 1980 to A00, it no longer sort in the correct chronoligcal order. In other words, try running your code with this:

    sales = [('account', ['A11', 'A00', 'C11', 'A12','B12','A13','B11']),
         ('date', ['01011997', '01021980', '07202005', '02011997', '12102001', '10012000', '11012001'])]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(sales)

Comment: The chronological order is correct - 1980 comes before 1997, not that it matters because A00 sorts before A11. The sort is performed on the account column _first_ then on the date column. Do you have another example were it is incorrect?

Comment: Thank you. I want to sort in alphabetical order and then in chronological order. I edited my example. I want to produce the results above. 1997 should appear at the top after the first letter in the ID have been arranged in alphabetical order. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Dan: but A00 sorts before A11. Your example is sorted neither alphabetically on the account column  nor chronologically on the date column.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which makes the date value sortable, and then create a temporary column in the dataframe while it is being sorted like:

#### Code:

```
def date_val(date):
    """ make a sortable date from out format """
    monthday, year = divmod(date, 10000)
    return year * 10000 + monthday

# create a sorted data frame using a temp column
df_sorted = df.assign(sortval=df.date.apply(date_val)) \
    .sort_values(['account', 'sortval']).drop('sortval', 1)
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd

sales = [('account', ['A11', 'C11', 'A12', 'B12', 'A13', 'B11']),
         ('date', [1011997, 7202005, 2011997, 12102001, 10012000, 11012001])
         ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(sales)

print(df.assign(sortval=df.date.apply(date_val))
    .sort_values(['account', 'sortval']).drop('sortval', 1))
```

#### Results:

```
  account      date
0     A11   1011997
2     A12   2011997
4     A13  10012000
5     B11  11012001
3     B12  12102001
1     C11   7202005
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it :

```
df.sort_values(['account', 'date'])
```

You need to use both account and date to sort the values. So putting them in one list object and using them to sort the dataframe.